# How to add ( RichTextBox1.Text) to a textfile.txt

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a textfile called foodadvices.txt   My app have a 2 richtextbox and button 
The button job is to add all texts in rtb1 to the textfile 
My idea is to read the textfile into rtb2
So the final code after reading textfile  is 
RichTextBox2.Text = richtextbox 1.text & richtextbox2.text

So if my rtb1.text is  lets go to park today 
And the rtb2 is lets go to cinema

The rtb2 after click on button should be

- Lets go to park today
- Lets go to cinema

  Then save yhe rtb2 to foodadvices.txt
  But the problem is the rtb2 wasnt like that after clicking on the button 
  It was
- Lets go to the park todaylets go to the cinema

Comment: Just add a vbNewLine constant between rtb1 and rtb2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a newline between the strings:

```
RichTextBox2.Text = richtextbox1.text & Environment.Newline & richtextbox2.text
```

If the first text already ends with a newline, you might want to skip adding one:

```
Dim text1 as String = richtextbox1.text
If Not test1.EndsWith(Environment.Newline) Then
  text1 = text1 & Environment.Newline
End If
RichTextBox2.Text = text1 & Environment.Newline & richtextbox2.text
```